# Regular expression to remove text outside the tags in a string

Tags: javascript, regex

Here is my string. Which will contain XML string
Like below

```
 var str= "<str>rvrv</str>rvrv<q1>vrvv</q1>vrvrv<q2>rtvrvr</q2>";
```

How can I remove text outside tags(text which does not belong to any tag.) using regular expression. Please help me on this.

Comment: regular expression is a regular language thus it is not suggested for you to use regex for this.

Comment: @AlanFoster Then how can I achieve this...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming your problem is only removing text not enclosed inside an element (and remaining code is well formed so you haven't strings like

```
var str= "<str>lorem <b>ipsum</str>";
```

) you could use a regular expression like this

```
var str= "<str>rvrv</str>rvrv<q1>vrvv</q1>vrvrv<q2>rtvrvr</q2>",
    elements = str.match(/<(.+?)>[^<]+<\/\1>/gi);

console.log(elements.join(''));
```

and this returns

```
<str>rvrv</str><q1>vrvv</q1><q2>rtvrvr</q2>
```

Note: to detect closing tags I used a backreference 
(see http://www.regular-expressions.info/brackets.html)